# CSS bootstrap alignment issue - pull right not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using simple css alignment of button on right hand side using pull right at http://www.inboundio.com/services, it is working for first block but it is not for second block. I am not sure what is going wrong, any help ?

You can see the code at the above url, I am also pasting it here too as per SO guidelines

```
<div class="span12  well">
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li>
<h3 style="color:#495B67">Heading</h3>
</li>
<li><br>
<p>Sample Text</p><br>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="span8 pull-left">
<strong><b>Your personal consultation will include:</b></strong> 
<p style="font-size: 17.5px">
</p><ol>
<li>How your current marketing strategy compares with your competitors</li>

</ol>
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="span4 pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"><b>Contact Us</b></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: I dont't see anythin wrong. You mean the orange buttons? They are both on the right side. But the html you pasted here is invalid, please correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because for first block you have set the css value :

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child{margin-left: 0px;}
```

that only work for first child

do it like `.row-fluid .well [class*="span"]{margin-left: 0px;}`

Comment: Thanks, I overrode and now it is looking fine

Answer (score 1):

There are some structure issues.

Replace the HTML part with the below code.

**Explanations:**

In previous box you have only two spans, but on second box, you have three spans without a wrap. So I added a wrap div with `row-fluid` class.

```
<div class="span12  well">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <ul class="nav nav-list">
         <li>
            <h3 style="color:#495B67">Inbound Marketing Consulting and Analysis</h3>
         </li>
         <li>
            <br>
            <p>Request a personalized marketing assessment and receive a 
               one-on-one consultation that will provide you with quick tips and 
               valuable insights that will transform your current marketing strategy.
            </p>
            <br>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8 pull-left">
         <strong><b>Your personal consultation will include:</b></strong> 
         <p style="font-size: 17.5px">
         </p>
         <ol>
            <li>How your current marketing strategy compares with your competitors</li>
            <li>Full website analysis and opportunities to improve</li>
            <li>SEO tips you can immediately implement into your website</li>
            <li>How to generate more leads via your website</li>
            <li>Blogging, email marketing, and social media strategy</li>
         </ol>
         <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="span4 pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"><b>Contact Us</b></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```